# When publishing a web site, my default document name keeps getting removed from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I have an ASP.NET web site project, which I'm publishing to IIS on my Win2k8 R2 server.  It has a default page called `login.aspx`.  I set that up on the published web site.

Trouble is, every time I publish a new version of the web site, the `login.aspx` entry gets erased from the "Default Document" settings of the web site in IIS.  This is very annoying.  How can I publish my web site from Visual Studio without wiping out the default page every time?

Comment: Are you getting any errors during publish (in the output window)? Try publishing to a local directory and see what happens. What is the build action of the file?

Comment: @Oded - nope, no errors at all.  I *am* publishing to a local directory; the VS environment is on the same server as IIS, and it's publishing directly to the inetpub\wwwroot folder.

Comment: Weird. I have never seen the publish action _delete_ a file on the target. What is the build action for the file (in the properties)?

Comment: @Oded - I think you misunderstood me.  It's not actually deleting the file.  It's changing IIS so that the "Default Document" does not contain that file name any more.  Will rephrase question for clarity.

Comment: @Shaul - I see. Check the web.config file. You might have an incorrect default document defined in it and are publishing it every time?

Comment: @Oded - nope. <authentication mode="Forms"><forms defaultUrl="secure/dashboard.aspx" loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="180"></forms></authentication>  Both of those forms exist.

Comment: You are probably using "sub site", and the default document list of the root website is blank - try adding default document (even dummy) to the root website and see if it helps. (taken from here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1169880.aspx)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - thanks - why not put that as an answer instead of a comment?  (Then I can give you answer credit!)

Comment: @Shaul - good point, done that now. Guess I wasn't sure enough.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using "sub site", and the default document list of the root website is blank.

Try adding default document (even dummy) to the root website and see if it helps.

(Taken from here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1169880.aspx)

Answer (score 21):

Try putting a defaultDocument in your site's web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- your other stuff -->

    <defaultDocument enabled="true">   
       <files>      
           <clear/>                 
           <add value="login.aspx"/>  
       </files>
    </defaultDocument>

</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. It's much nicer to have this in the site's config, rather than rely on the server root website to be set up. It's much more explicit and can be source controlled. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

when the login.aspx is added to subsite. it's type 'local'. it gives this error.
you should add this page to the servere itself.
click the server and then choose the feature view--> iis--- default document then right click to add your "login.aspx" page.

now you should see this in default document of all your sub sites and it will not be erased in publish or server restart.

this is my personal exceperience

Omar kamel